# Segmentation fault in proxy server program

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to create a simple proxy server in c. I have used this [url parser](http://draft.scyphus.co.jp/lang/c/url_parser.html) to parse the http request from the client. It returns a pointer to this structure:

```
struct parsed_url {
    char *scheme;               /* mandatory */
    char *host;                 /* mandatory */
    char *port;                 /* optional */
    char *path;                 /* optional */
    char *query;                /* optional */
    char *fragment;             /* optional */
    char *username;             /* optional */
    char *password;             /* optional */
};
```

When I print the host name after parsing a http request from a client, it displays correct result like "www.google.com". But when I pass this hostname to gethostbyname(), it gives me segmentation fault. I am not bale to figure out why this happens. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "url_parser.h"
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    struct hostent *host;
    int s1,s2,s3,len;
    int port;
    char ip[100];
    char path[100];
    int p;
    struct parsed_url *url = NULL;
    int n;
    char buffer[500];
    char site[500];
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        perror("can't bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(s1,10) == -1) {
        perror("coudnt't listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    len = sizeof(client);
    s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
    if(s2 == -1) {
        perror("coudnt aceept");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    n = recv(s2,buffer,500,0);
    if(n < 0) {
        perror("not recieved");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer[n] = '\0';

    url = parse_url(buffer);
    bzero((char *)&client,sizeof(client));
    client.sin_port = htons(80);
    printf("%s %d",url->host,strlen(url->host));
    host = gethostbyname((char *)url->host);
    if(!host) {
        herror("host error");
    }
    bcopy((char *)host->h_addr,(char *)&client.sin_addr.s_addr,host->h_length);
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s3 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);


    if(connect(s3,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client)) == -1) {
        perror("can't connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(site,"GET http://%s/ HTTP/1.0\n\n",url->host);
    n = send(s3,site,strlen(site),0);
    if(n < 0) {
        perror("message not sent");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        memset(site,0,sizeof(site));
        n = recv(s3,site,500,0);
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("coudnot read");
            exit(1);
        }
        //site[n] = '\0';
        send(s2,site,strlen(site),0);
    }
    close(s1);
    close(s2);
    return 0;
}
```

The url_parser uses [this](http://draft.scyphus.co.jp/lang/c/url_parser.html) to parse.

Comment: `buffer[n] = '\0';` n can be 500 here. Also: recv() can return zero.  (or even a partial read ...) `send(s2,site,strlen(site),0);` site is not null-terminated (and n can again be 500)

Comment: Then how should I mark the end of buffer?

Comment: You should not mark it. You just need to remember how large it is. (that is the returnvalue `n=recv()` Also: you should check if you have enough data to parse the request/response ( upto "\r\n\r\n" , IIRC)

Comment: Actually everything works fine if I put hostname directly into gethostbyname. For example,,gethostbyname("www.iiita.ac.in") works. But parsing and passing url->host to gethostbyname gives seg fault

Comment: I'm just pointing out the obvious errors. And: the program *could* work fine, given request of < 500 bytes and no partial reads.

Comment: You are probably incorrectly use `url_parser` library. You should check the return value of `parse_url(buffer)` to avoid segmentation fault. It probably returns `NULL`.

Comment: It doesn't return NULL. I alsp printed the url->host and it printed correctly.

Comment: Also you are not quitting your program in case `host` is `NULL`, as returned by `gethostbyname`. This will cause segfault.

Comment: Yup, that was causing seg fault. I now exit when it's NULL. Now I get unknown host error.